# Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR SendAsync args

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

Can somebody explain to me why they used `arg1, arg2 ....` in `AspNetCore.SignalR.SendAsync` method, instead of `params object[] args`?

Is there a better way of doing that?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg9ID.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CancellationToken` is optional. You'll notice in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnectionextensions.sendasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) that it's defined as:

```
System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = null
```

(Although in the [actual code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/3cd5054eb5d8851b25881cd05cccb931aaa022e6/src/SignalR/clients/csharp/Client.Core/src/HubConnectionExtensions.SendAsync.cs#L23) it's `= default`, so I think the docs are wrong)

[Optional arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments) must come last.

But also, using infinite parameters with the [`params`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params) keyword must also come last. So you cannot use both in the same method definition.

An alternative could have been to create the method with the `CancellationToken` as the second-last parameter, and an overload without it:

```
public static Task SendAsync (this HubConnection hubConnection, string methodName, params object[] args) {
    return SendAsync(hubConnection, methodName, default, args);
}

public static Task SendAsync (this HubConnection hubConnection, string methodName, CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] args) {
    ...
}
```

That effectively makes the `CancellationToken` optional. However, in this specific case, it would also prevent you from sending a `CancellationToken` as the first argument (in the `args` array) and not in the `cancellationToken` parameter, if you needed to do that for whatever reason.

But Microsoft also has the standard of putting the `CancellationToken` as the last parameter in every async method they write. So they would be breaking that pattern if they did this. So they settled on only allowing [10 arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.client.hubconnectionextensions.sendasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_SignalR_Client_HubConnectionExtensions_SendAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_SignalR_Client_HubConnection_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like they wanted a `CancellationToken` as a last argument. This is a common practice to have it as a last argument of a method.

```
await SendAsync(..., arg1, arg2, arg3, cancellationToken);
await SendAsync(..., cancellationToken, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

I much rather prefer the 1st line than the second one. You can only use params as a last argument of a method, which would not let them have a cancellation token as a last argument. So they decided to implement multiple overloads with different number of arguments, which allows them to put `cancellationToken` as a very last argument of each overload.

Comment: Yeah because it has a default value, but one person says that the developer is an idiot and he has a better implementation of that.

Comment: But why they have used arg1, arg2, arg3 not params?

Comment: @Sergey `params object[] args` has to be the very last argument(s)

Comment: Why they have not done it in another way? Or there are no other better ways?

Comment: @Sergey you can't have a method with signature `SendAsync(... params object[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))`. So I'd say, the only other option is to pass arguments in collection as a single argument.